# How to open a programmatically protected PDF file [Not password protected]

Tags: java, c#, android, pdf

There is a android app named [taaghche](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ir.mservices.mybook&hl=en_US&gl=US) which you can purchase and read pdf books etc...

I purchased a book and I want to be able to read it on PC not android, and also be able to highlight the text (which is not allowed in the app), But The app stores the pdfs so that the pdf files only opens in the app itself and if you try to open the pdf in another device you'll get the error:

[image]

Note that the app actually stores the pdf along with a file with no extension and the same name.

I think the app uses the file with no extension to give permission to the pdf file to be opened.

Here is the two files in a zip to download and have a look.

http://langfox.ir/download/pdfs.zip

Any idea or solution or clue to open this file is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to check if what you are trying to do is actually legal.  Essentially, it seems that you are trying to bypass the protection on content sold by someone else.

Answer (score 1):

The pdf looks encoded/encrypted (I maybe wrong) but I would expect to see a Pdf header, and I don't.

The file without an extension is a JFIF file (JPEG File Interchange Format), if you change the extension to Jpg, or JFIF, you should be able to view it as an image. Or in C# you can just use the `Bitmap` or `Image` class to load it

```
Image.FromFile(theFileName);
```

Comment: Thank you plus one...Is there any way to decrypt this?

Comment: @SaraRee not that I know of, however you can view the other file as an image.